# Media Server died ,android play video from sdcard

Tags: android

I used video view to play video from sdcard

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        videoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/"+"hanhdong.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.start();
```

but when i run ,I have a error that 
media server died .
MediaPlayer Error (100,0).
Please help me.Thank you!

Comment: Post your log cat @HuynhHan

Comment: My log cat show : media player server died .MediaPlayer Error(100,0)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a error listener to video view

```
videoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
```

Then you can handle the errors gracefully in [onError](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html#onError(android.media.MediaPlayer,%20int,%20int)) like

```
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) 
 {
  if (what == 100)
    {
    videoView.stopPlayback();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,ActivityToStart.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is ActivityToStart ?.It show Error(-38,0) and don't stop run ! @Neeraj Kumar

Comment: Activity to start can be any activity to handle or display errors. If you are gettining error on  videoView.stopPlayback() then put it in try catch.